# SQL > edit select sum(column) group by hour for dataset

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, report, reportviewer

I am using this sql code

```
select DATEPART(hour, date) as oHour, SUM(orders.total) as total from orders group by DATEPART(HOUR, date)
```

in C# dataset to create chart in ReportViewer control.

Example : sql query return this:

```
oHour     total
---------------
8           589
11         1899
12          890
```

The problem is that the SQL query returns only those hours, had a track record.
**I need to return records for each hour.**
Example

```
oHour    total
--------------
8          589
9            0
10           0
11        1899
12         890
```

How do I edit the SQL query?

Comment: Hours 9 and 10 not exist in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
    s.number as oHour, 
    SUM(isnull(o.total,0)) as total 
from 
    master..spt_values s
    left join orders o on s.number = DATEPART(HOUR, date)
where
    s.type = 'P'
    and s.number between 0 and 23
group by 
    s.number
```

This code returns sum for every hour in day

Answer (score 0):

```
 select DATEPART(hour, date) as oHour, SUM(COALESCE(orders.total, 0)) as total
 from orders
 group by DATEPART(HOUR, date)
```

The SUM operator is returning null for orders.total where there are no orders. Using COALESCE it will choose the data type of the highest precedence (where all types are higher precedence than NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is ugly, but here's a possibility since the other answer probably won't work in your situation, and nothing else has been posted yet.

- I have no idea if this is bad performance-wise. It's probably fine.
- I don't know if you can somehow generate a temporary table on-the-fly instead of doing two dozen unions.
- You could actually just create a new table, with one record in it for each hour, and a "total" column that has `0` in it for each record, then do a `union all` on that table before doing your `group by`.
- This was done in DB2, which is the only environment I have access to at the moment. I don't have a `DATEPART`, so you might have to make a few modifications before this works.
- Not sure what environment you're in, but Oracle uses `dual`, DB2 typically uses `sysibm.sysdummy1`, and I don't think you need either for SQL Server (`SELECT 0, 0` should be enough).

Query:

```
SELECT oHour, SUM(total) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT HOUR(date) AS oHour, total FROM parts.g_orders
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 16, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 17, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 18, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 19, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 21, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 22, 0 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 23, 0 FROM DUAL)
GROUP BY oHour
```